# Each vertex of the square has a value which is randomly chosen from a set.

Tags: statistics, problem-solving, independence

I don't need so much help computing this question (yet). However, I am still at the point of understanding what the question is really asking. If anyone understands it, and can explain it, that would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

I understand what pairwise and mutually independent are. I just don't understand how I would be able to show that. From what I understand, each vertex is randomly selected from {1, 2, ..., 6}. So say edge 1 is connected to a vertex that randomly selected 2, and another vertex that randomly selected 3 from the set, then the pdf would be X1 = 0 (because they are not the same value). Now say edge 2 connects two vertices that have randomly selected the same value, say 4, then its pdf would be X2 = 1 (since the vertices have the same value). I understand that they are pairwise independent (each set of pairs are independent), because they are randomly selected from the set {1, 2, ..., 6} but how can I show that? And how are X1, X2, X3, and X4 not mutually independent?

Comment: Please edit the question to let us know which part(s) you don't understand. That way we won't have to rewrite (not "dumb down") the whole question.

Comment: For instance, do you know what it means for two random variables to be independent? Can you show that $X_1$ and $X_3$ are independent? What about $X_1$ and $X_2$?

Comment: Could you also please write out the question rather than posting an image?

Comment: "I understand what pairwise and mutually independent are. I just don't understand how I would be able to show that. From what I understand, each vertex is randomly selected from {1, 2, ..., 6}. So say edge 1 is connected to a vertex that randomly selected 2, and another vertex that randomly selected 3 from the set, then the pdf would be X1 = 0 (because they are not the same value). " The pdf would not be $X_1 = 0$. That doesn't even make sense. What's true is that the value of the random variable  $X_1$ would be $0$ on the point $(2, 3)$ of the sample space, namely,  all pairs of labelings.

Comment: sorry, I have edited my post, regarding my understanding of the question! @EthanBolker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So say edge 1 is connected to a vertex that randomly selected 2, and another vertex that randomly selected 3 from the set, then the pdf would be $X_1 = 0$ (because they are not the same value).

Instead of fixing values for the vertices, look at the probability that $X_i=1$; let's call this $P(X_i)$. What is $P(X_1)$? What is $P(X_1 \cap X_2)$? How about $P(X_1 \cap X_2 \cap X_3)$ and $P(X_1 \cap X_2 \cap X_3 \cap X_4)$? Now use the definitions of pairwise independence and mutual independence.

Note also that for pairwise independence you should check the two kinds of pairs of edges: those that share a vertex, and those that are disjoint.

Comment: So the sample space for X1 would be: {(1,1), (1,2),.. (2,1), (2,2), ...(3,1),.. (4,1), ..(5,1..), (6,1), .., (6,6)} and P(X1) = 6/36 = 1/6. 

The same would go for X2: P(X2) = 1/6.

Now for P(X1∩X2), wouldn't it be the same thing, equaling 1/6? since they both would have the exact same sample space? {(1,1), (2,2), (3,3),...}.

which then they would not be pairwise independent, since 1/6 ≠ (1/6)(1/6)=(1/36)?

Comment: You're right that $P(X_i)=1/6$ for all $i$. But $P(X_1\cap X_2)$ is not $1/6$. Assuming $X_1$ and $X_2$ correspond to edges that share a vertex, the sample space is $\{(1,1,1), (1,1,2), \ldots, (6,6,6)\}$; you should get $P(X_1\cap X_2)=1/36$. To put it another way, roll three (six-sided) dice: what is the probability that they're all the same?

Answer (score 2):

That $X_1$ and $X_3$ are independent is obvious.

Let $e_2=\{v_1,v_2\}$ and $e_3=\{v_2,v_3\}$. Whatever number vertex $v_2$ gets assigned we have $P(X_2=1)=P(X_3=1)={5\over6}$ and $P(X_2=1\ \wedge\ X_3=1)={25\over36}$; and similarly for the other cases.

On the other hand, if we, e.g., know that $X_1=X_2=X_3=0$ then we can be sure that $X_4=0$ as well. It follows that the $X_i$ are not mutually independent.